# Chrome does not re-draw properly on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, windows-8.1

There are a lot of problems with Chrome (24.0.1312.14 beta || But all this happened before update also) on Windows 8. Problems and explanations are listed below:

1. **Google Chrome re-draw time**: When I switch tabs, the window retains the content of the previous tab and displays that even if I move my mouse, if only refreshes (re-draws) when there is a change on the webpage (like on hover) or I do a select all (or scroll). One thing to note is that the hover and select happens on the **real** page and not the retained image-like thing of the older webpage.
2. **Chrome is slow and laggy**: Websites such as Facebook and Twitter (and more) have gone extremely laggy on Chrome (Win 8). When I was using Windows 7, I never experienced a lag or something. 
   Also when using HTML-5 Websites, the transition (the `-webkit-transition` in CSS) goes extremely slow at times.
3. **Plugins Crash**: Plugins like Flash Player, Shockwave Player, and more that are in-built into Chrome Crashes a lot, even when doing simple tasks like playing YouTube Videos, displaying ads or something.
4. **Chrome Crashes**: Chrome has crashed over 100 times in the past month. Google Chrome just crashes randomly or I don't know the reason.
5. **Random Page crashes**: Chrome results `chrome://crash/`(Copy-Paste this in address bar) on random pages even when the page is just loaded, I understand that this can happen on heavy HTML5 or JS websites but what about HTML only websites?
6. **Computer Freeze**: Chrome sometimes, randomly, freezes my computer. Freeze in the sense, none of the other apps are also working. It's like the whole system freezes, I can not even switch to other apps. I am sure that this is because of Chrome since this happens only when Chrome is active.

Most of the things above happens on Super User also, Super User never had any problem when 
using Chrome on Windows 7.

---

**UPDATE 1**: [@magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/q/509530/120833#comment610034_509530) Commented for trying to disable Hardware Acceleration. I tried it, it somewhat solved the problem but din't fix it. I am still experiencing all the above issues but less frequently (maybe because Chrome Restarted Completely)

**UPDATE 2**: [@avirk](https://superuser.com/q/509530/120833#comment610052_509530) asked me to try a Stable Version of Chrome and Firefox, I din't experience any lag in Firefox, a little (negligible) lag in Chrome 22 (Maybe because its a new copy of Chrome, I haven't used it much).

**UPDATE 3**: [@NothingsImpossible](https://superuser.com/q/509530/120833#comment615846_509530) said that He is also experiencing the same problem on Windows Server 2008! This seams to be a major issue now. He also said that GPU load is also high at the same time! Even I saw the same thing.

**UPDATE 4**:  Recently, Chrome updated to v24 Stable (I am using stable from a long time now). I was experiencing this problem a lot less in Chrome 23, but this is back in Chrome 24. Seams like Chrome 24 is the most affected from this bug, as this same problem was high in Chrome 24 beta also.

**UPDATE 5**: Chrome was updated to v25 Stable. This problem is 99% Gone, it is still there in 1% of the cases. One such example is when I leave chrome inactive for a while with a few tabs open, the tabs go black and no activity can get them back to active state. If I open a new tab, the new tab is OK but the others are still black, I need to close all those tabs.

**UPDATE 6**: Chrome updated to v27 Stable channel, this problem is nearly gone. This does happen occasionally, but not as frequent as in earlier versions of Chrome.

**UPDATE 7**: I am on Chrome v35.0.1916.114 Stable, Windows 8.1 Pro Update 1. Some of the other problems appears to be back. Chrome is slow and laggy again. Re-draw time is getting worse.

---

Is anybody else experiencing such issues? Does anybody have a solution to **any** of these?

Comment: have you tried to disable the hardware acceleration in Chrome? Does this fix it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Let me try that!

Comment: That somewhat solves some problem but dosen't ends the problem!

Comment: Try to install a stable release of Chrome. Also check with Firefox for lag problem.

Comment: @avirk OK, I'll try that also!

Comment: There is no lag in Firefox, but there is a little (negligible) lag in Chrome 22!(maybe because its a new copy - I have not used it a lot)

Comment: the stable channel should be version 23. If you still have crashes, collect dumps (with WER service), open them in WinDbg (point to MS symbol and Chrome symbol server) and run !analyze -v. What do you see in the dumps?

Comment: Yeah stable release is 23 and if you feel little lag then it's normal as chrome is sucking from last few updates. There are a lots of bug with new release of chrome. I advise you to always use a stable release.

Comment: I know that current stable release is 23 but I downloaded 22 from oldapps.com just for a test!

Comment: So does it solved your problems somehow?

Comment: @avirk Yes, it seams like there is less lag on Chrome 22, but this maybe only because its a new copy of Chrome, this problem doesn't appears to be there when I start Chrome!

Comment: Using 23.0.1271.95 on Windows Server 2008, the tab switching lag is horrible, and I can assure it is not related to swapping, hard disk is not read during the switch, but CPU usage is very high. It is ironic that I am ditching chrome because of its slowness.

Comment: @NothingsImpossible You have the same issue! Even I am now using Firefox because of the same reason!

Comment: How much RAM do you have? I've seen the slow redraw issue on an XP laptop with 2GB.

Comment: I am running Windows 8 Pro WMC edition with 8GB ram.

Comment: For #2: Might be overkill, but you could [`xperf` the process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pigscanfly/archive/2008/02/09/xperf-a-new-tool-in-the-windows-sdk.aspx) while switching between tabs a lot and seeing what Chrome's doing in that time.

Comment: Do you need to use chrome? Try firefox instead.

Comment: @handuel Well, that's not a solution. I use ALL the browsers. Chrome being primary. This problem is nearly gone with the v27 of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I had some comparable issues and resolved them by launching Chrome, going to the three horizontal bars in the upper right corner ('Customize and control Google Chrome'), and selecting 'relaunch chrome in Windows 8 mode'. Solved the issue!

Comment: I tried it, chrome works fine for a few minutes and then results the same problem also I want to run chrome perfectly in the Desktop mode.

Comment: I've experienced no problems after switching back to Desktop mode (several days and numerous restarts). I'm using Chrome version 23.0.1271.97.

Comment: Recently, Chrome has updated to V24 stable, This problem was a bit less in Chrome 23 (nearly nil).

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8, or somehow transferred your Chrome profile from your Windows 7 to Windows 8 installation, you may try deleting your user's Chrome profile and then creating a new one (saving the bookmarks and any other information that you need, not including settings).

I have heard of this issue before, and it seems many people have experienced this, but from what I gather, it usually occurs when upgrading from Win7 to Win8 or when transferring the Chrome profile for the user, not on fresh installs, and in most of the cases that I've found via Google, deleting the user's Chrome profile seemed to have solved it.

You can find many of these reports by Googling "windows 8 chrome switching tabs" (without the quotes). Hope this helps.

Comment: I have not upgraded from Win 7 to Win 8. This is a fresh install on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a bug with the graphics card drivers for Windows 8, try using the graphics card drivers for windows 7.

Before you do my fist suggestion, go to the website of the manufacturer of your computer and download updated drivers for Windows 8 for the architecture you are running (32 bits or 64 bits -- must match your current running architecture.  Control Panel > system will tell you if you are running 32 bits or 64 bits).

After downloading and updating every single drivers for your computer (Graphics/Video, Sound, Network, WIFI, etc) restart your computer and see if the problem has been fixed.  If not, then try your original Windows 7 drivers for the Video Card that used to work properly when you had Windows 7 installed on the same computer.

For that, you will have to force the install by using the "let me pick the location of the driver" option when installing the driver using Device Manager.  Keep in mind that Windows 7 drivers does work under Windows 8, I have installed many Windows 7 drivers for Windows 8 computers when there were no Windows 8 drivers available and I have had never an issue.

Windows 8 runs using Windows 7 technology, the driver framework for windows 8 is exactly the same for windows 7 so if you were never having trouble with windows 7 try the same windows 7 drivers you were running and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Its not a driver issue. I have disabled the dedicated graphics card on this machine when I installed Windows 8 because it was using too much of power. I have Intel HD 3000 running, with latest drivers that are built for Windows 8 64Bit (My system config).